# Linkedin API does not return phone number

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve some information about the user via Linkedin API, such as name, location, email address, phone number(s). The first three ones are returned perfectly, but the phone number is not returned for some reason (the field isn't even included in the return set). I have added it later, so I guess in might be some caching on the Linkedin's side.

All the permissions are included both in request and in the app's settings, the scope is: `r_basicprofile r_emailaddress r_fullprofile r_contactinfo w_share`

The query URL is: `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,phone-numbers,location:(name),email-address)?format=json`

What might me the reason? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Linkedin api doens't provide the phone number. They only provide the basic profile

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Why is it included into the list of available fields in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An additional investigation has shown that to obtain any field from the full profile (including phone) it is necessary to request an ability to use this permission for your application via [Apply with LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) program.